# Formula with multiple text count

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets with cells similar to this:

Column A contains GENDER (`Man` or `Woman`),
Column B contains chosen color (can be multiple colors, ie. `Black, Blue, White`).

[image: Sample data]

What I would like to do is to count how many times `Man` chooses `Black`, `White` or `Blue` color. I tried this formula for each of the colors but it's not working:

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM( ('Submissions'!A2:A1095 = "Man" ) * 'Submissions'!B2:B897 = "*Black*" ) ) )
```

Can you help me with the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
= arrayformula(COUNTIF(A:A&B:B, "Man" & "*Black*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ranges are the same size.

Comment: The formula is the exact copy. I have double checked.

Comment: The thing is though that data is entered to the sheet (cells) by web app. So it is impossible to parse columnB into separate columns. That is why I need a formula which will do the trick.

Comment: Separator is <br> and there is a limit of max.5 colors in the one cell (1-5 colors).